# Run Artisan command in controller method on AWS Beanstalk

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I hosted my Laravel Application on AWS Beanstalk, I created a Postgres RDS and connect with to my application, the application can confirm that there is a connection to the database
[image: confirmation to database connection]

but, for some reasons, I cannot ssh to the database using Putty, to run my artisan commands, so I am not able to run my migrations, I am looking for other means to run my migrations.
I tried using **.ebextension/init.config**,
[image]but when I push my code, The CodePipeline is not deploying it, so I decide to run the migration with a controller.
[image: Artisan controller]
The route
[image: Route]
I ran that command on my local, it works, but when I run it on Production, I am getting **500 | Server Error**, when I check the log, this is what I got
[image: log]
`2021/11/05 00:42:08 [error] 3918#3918: *43 open() "/var/www/html/public/artisan/command/migrate" failed (2: No such file or directory),`

my question is why is the command attaching the URL to a directory,

and how can I run my migration on AWS Beanstalk instance

Answer (score 0):

This wont work as when you are trying to deploy the app, the code is not yet there. You would have to write the elastic beanstalk hooks to execute after the code is there in the directory and then run commands using hook files.